# Graphic view PB12.6 version build 4091

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, powerbuilder-conversion

I have a problem in newer versions of `PowerBuilder`, that before I did not. At this point, I have installed the `PB12.6` version, build 4091.

The problem is when I open a window with a context area, this window sometimes gets a bad graphic aspect. You can see in the following image.

```
PB12.6 version 3506 ---- its working Correctly
PB12.6 version 4088 ---- problem with context area
PB12.6 version 4091 ---- problem with context area
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks

[image: please click here to view image of the problem]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe that you'd be better off contacting the vendor through the usual support channels.

Comment: If you don't understand the question, perhaps you shouldn't comment.